# file names with space character in conk configuration

Tags: linux, conky

I am trying to load an image in Conky (running under Linux), where the image has got space characters in its path. like this:

```
${execp echo "\${image \"$(qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Metadata | grep artUrl | cut -b 22- | sed 's@+@ @g;s@%@\\x@g'| xargs -0 printf "%b")\" -p 0,140 -s 100x100 -n}"}
```

This line reads the artcover property of currently playing audio in VLC and displays it. but since the path has got space characters, Conky interprets the space as argument separating character. How do I fix that?